# Have I hit a dead end in Universal Paperclips?

Tags: universal-paperclips

This is my second time playing Universal Paperclips. The first was years ago, and I made it to the end. This time, I seem to be stuck after releasing the Hypno Drones

[image]

As soon as I entered this second phase, the Clips Per Second was 0 and has stayed that way. I let it play on a bit and opened up Power and Wire Production but I'm still not producing anything.

Is this a bug? I feel like I've entered this phase with a piece missing. (I walked away from the screen for a while so may have clicked Hypno Drones without first doing something else that the designer expected.)

Comment: Did this ever get fixed? Save and reload??